# PHP strange str_split array output

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Ok, im having troubles figuring out why my str_split is giving strange array output, this is the code:

```
$test = array(0 => array(53, 22, 12, "string"),
            1 => array(94, 84, 94, "string1"),
            2 => array(56, 45, 104, "string2"),
            3 => array(33, 21, 20, 23, "string3"),
            4 => array(44, 55, 66, 77)
            );

$newArray = array();            
$keys = array_keys($test);
for($i=0; $i < count($test); $i++){
foreach($test[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value){
}
$output = str_split($key);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Array output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => 3
)

Array
(
[0] => 3
)

Array
(
[0] => 3
)

Array
(
[0] => 4
)

Array
(
[0] => 3
)
```

And im expecting output like this:

```
Array ([0] => 3
       [1] => 3
       [2] => 3
       [3] => 4
       [4] => 3
      )
```

Im wondering why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: Whats the sense of the empty `foreach` loop? Populating the `$key`? Could be done easier.

Comment: There is one extra bracket there, or one is missing. Something is wrong with these loops

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, i.e. how expected output is corresponding with input array?

Comment: Im trying to extract keys from multidimensional array and store them in 1d array

Comment: And I do not see any point in str_split()ing an integer value.

Comment: @Greedy The verified solution will work for the string position to be constant , so I edited my answer, now for change in position of string will not effect the result in my answer. I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the output given, [you would just do](https://eval.in/540322):

```
<?php

$test = array(0 => array(53, 22, 12, "string"),
        1 => array(94, 84, 94, "string1"),
        2 => array(56, 45, 104, "string2"),
        3 => array(33, 21, 20, 23, "string3"),
        4 => array(44, 55, 66, 77)
        );

foreach ($test as $row) {
    $output[] = count($row)-1;          // non-associative, so the last key is
}                                       // just the length of the array minus 1

print_r($output);

?>
```

as the sub-arrays are not associative.

If they are, replace the line inside the loop with:

```
    $keys = array_keys($row);           // get the keys of the row
    $output[] = $keys[count($keys)-1];  // and access the last of them
```

Comment: Thx, that's what I always try to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

with your code the solution is, but it is not an efficient way of doing it.

```
<?php
$test = array(0 => array(53, 22, 12, "string"),
            1 => array(94, 84, 94, "string1"),
            2 => array(56, 45, 104, "string2"),
            3 => array(33, 21, 20, 23, "string3"),
            4 => array(44, 55, 66, 77)
            );

$newArray = array();            
$keys = array_keys($test);
for($i=0; $i < count($test); $i++){
foreach($test[$i] as $key => $value){
    $output[$i] = str_split($key)[0];
}
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";  
}
var_dump($output);
```

### output

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => string '3' (length=1)
```

**But by changing it to this will work, for arrays when the string position is not constant .**

```
<?php
$test = array(0 => array(53, 22, 12, "string"),
            1 => array(94, 84, 94, "string1"),
            2 => array(56, 45, 104, "string2"),
            3 => array(33, 21, "string3", 20, 23),
            4 => array(44, 55, 66, 77)
            );



$newArray = array();            
$keys = array_keys($test);
for($i=0; $i < count($test); $i++){
foreach($test[$i] as $key => $value){
    if(is_string($value)){
       unset($test[$i][$key]);
    }
    $output[$i] = count($test[$i]);
}
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";  
}
var_dump($output);
```

### output

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 3
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 4
```